# Is global variable static in python

Tags: python, variables

This is my utils.py

```
detector = cv2.mcc.CCheckerDetector_create()

def process(): 
  print(detector)
```

main.py

```
for i in range(100): 
  process()
```

This question might sound stupid.
As the variable detector in process() is initiated everytime I call process() if I put it inside the function process() so I change it as a global variable. Will it be created only once?

Comment: `As the variable detector in process() is initiated everytime I call process()`: no, it is not.

Comment: As the variable detector in process() is initiated everytime I call process() if I put it inside the function process() ?

Comment: If you put the initialization, that is, if I understand correctly, the call to `CCheckerDetector_create`, in the body of a function you call 100 times, then the initialization will occur 100 times, yes. If you don't, and put that code outside any function, it will occur only once.

Answer (score 0):

The variable will be created when the code that creates it is executed.  In the case of `detector`, that code is at the module level.  It will be executed when the module is imported, and never again.  There's no code anywhere in your example to create any objects to replace it.